# Laravel: How to show image created with Image Intervention in view file

Tags: laravel

I am using Image Intervention to merge two images in Controller.
Now I want to show this image in view file but I get this error.

> Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException Image source not readable

Here are my codes.

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\User;
use InterventionImage;

public function qrcode(User $user)
{
    $qrcode_path = ('public/storage/qrcode/' . $user->random . '.png');
    $qrcode_img = InterventionImage::make($qrcode_path);
    $qrcode_template_path = ('public/storage/home/qrcode_template.png');
    $qrcode_template_img = InterventionImage::make($qrcode_template_path);

    $qrcode_merged = $qrcode_template_img->insert($qrcode_img, 'center');

    return view('test.myqrcode')->with([
        'user' => $user,
        'qrcode_template_img' => $qrcode_merged
    ]);
}
```

**view**

```
<img src="{{$qrcode_merged}}">
```

I appreciate if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I should do. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Comment: Assuming `InteventionImage` is `Image` from the library "Intervention" try to add `encode()` like this: `make(...)->encode()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the image first

and the value of the src attribute must be the path to your image, not an instance of **Intervention\Image\Image**

make sure you saved the first image in **'your_root_project/storage/app/public/qrcode'**
, the second in **'your_root_project/storage/app/public/home'**
And already run command "**php artisan storage:link**"

```
$qrcode_path = public_path('/storage/qrcode/' . $user->random . '.png');
$qrcode_img = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($qrcode_path);
$qrcode_template_path = public_path('/storage/home/qrcode_template.png');
$qrcode_template_img = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($qrcode_template_path);

$your_image_name = "merged_image_name";
$path_show_in_view = 'storage/qrcode/' . $your_image_name  . '.png';
$qrcode_merged->save(public_path("/storage/qrcode/" . $your_image_name . ".png"));
return view('test.myqrcode')->with([
    'user' => $user,
    'path_show_in_view' => $path_show_in_view 
]);
```

**view**

```
<img src="{{asset($path_show_in_view)}}">
```

Comment: Hi there,
Is it absolutely necessary to save the image?
I want to do it without saving the image.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi there, Is it absolutely necessary to save the image? I want to do it without saving the image.

you can encode to base64 if you don't want to save it

```
$qrcode_path = public_path('/storage/qrcode/' . $user->random . '.png');
$qrcode_img = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($qrcode_path);
$qrcode_template_path = public_path('/storage/home/qrcode_template.png');
$qrcode_template_img = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($qrcode_template_path);

$qrcode_merged = $qrcode_template_img->insert($qrcode_img, 'center');

return view('test.myqrcode')->with([
    'user' => $user,
    'qrcode_merged' => $qrcode_merged 
]);
```

**view**

```
<img src="{{$qrcode_merged->encode('data-url')}}"/>
```